# InitialRAMPercentage doesn't set initial heap size

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection

We are running our Java application with OpenJDK 17.0.7 in a Docker container with these arguments (these are only relevant to my question):
`-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=75.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1G -XX:+UseG1GC`

Here is a picture from JDK Mission Control showing how the application starts:

[image: Run an application with InitialRAMPercentage]

You can see that Committed size was not the same all the time. It started at 3GiB and then it grew up to ~6GiB.

Then I changed VM Arguments to use Xms/Xmx instead of RAMPercentage:
`-Xms6G -Xmx6G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1G -XX:+UseG1GC`

And now I see the picture I expected to see - Committed size is equals to 6GiB from the startup:
[image: Run an application with Xms/XMx]

Is it an expected behavior of InitialRAMPercentage? Shouldn't it work the same way as Xms? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common misconception is that the initial heap size is the minimum heap size. They are actually different and can be configured separately: `-XX:InitialHeapSize` vs. `-XX:MinHeapSize`.

In JDK 17, `-Xms` is a shortcut to set both `InitialHeapSize` and `MinHeapSize` to the same value. In contrast, `-XX:InitialRAMPercentage` affects `InitialHeapSize` only, and therefore heap may shrink below the initial size.

If you want to prevent heap from resizing at runtime, disable heap shrinking with `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=100`, or disable adaptive size policy altogether: `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`.

Note: `-XX:MinRAMPercentage` does not help. Its name is confusing: the argument configures `MaxHeapSize`, not `MinHeapSize` - see [JDK-8278492](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8278492)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `MaxHeapFreeRatio=100` works pretty well in my case.
`Xms` shortcut's explanation is also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add this flag as well:

```
-XX:+UseContainerSupport
```

From docs you will see that this will work only with Linux x64 platforms:

> -XX:-UseContainerSupport
> The VM now provides automatic container detection support, which allows the VM to determine the amount of memory and number of processors that are available to a Java process running in docker containers. It uses this information to allocate system resources. This support is only available on Linux x64 platforms. If supported, the default for this flag is true, and container support is enabled by default. It can be disabled with -XX:-UseContainerSupport.

This flag can help also:

```
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
```

> -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
> Requests the VM to touch every page on the Java heap after requesting it from the operating system and before handing memory out to the application. By default, this option is disabled and all pages are committed as the application uses the heap space.

Answer (score -1):

we are seeing the same issue as Popandopolos here.
More precisely we are seeing a behavior change between Java11 and Java17.

Indeed, we've recently migrated our containers apps from Java11 to Java17 (our runtime container env is RedHat OpenShift 4.12).

We've always been using the following options:
"-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=60 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch"
in order to guarantee the Heap would never be resized and therefore would never impact the runtime performance of our latency critical application.

With those settings, using Java11, we have always witnessed committed heap being set to 60% of the container memory limit for the whole lifetime of the container.

After moving to Java17, it is like if InitialRAMPercentage was no more honored.
Committed heap starts very low and moves during the lifetime of the container.
If we -Xms/-Xmx instead of -XX:InitialRAMPercentage/-XX:MaxRAMPercentage, Java17 behaves exactly as Java11 would with -XX:InitialRAMPercentage/-XX:MaxRAMPercentage.

So, the behavior definitely changed between Java11 and Java17...
and currently getting back to -Xms/-Xmx seems the only way to unblock our testing.

HTH
++Cyrille

Comment: I can suggest to check @apangin answer.  `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=100` works for me

Comment: Works for us too!